# Search a column of strings in a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, string, loops

I am working on a function that takes two cells and looks for them in a column of strings that is in a different sheet:

```vb
Sub search_cellID()
'

'

' Print argument should be written in V7
    Range("V7").Select      
    
'flag for the loop
    i = 2

    if    Instr( -16, 'Input'!RiC11,1 ) =  -16 Then
        Print  'Input'!RiC2
            
    Elseif  Instr( -1, 'Input'!RiC11) = -1 Then
        Print 'Input'!RiC2
            
    Else: i = i + 1
            
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in this way because there are several errors. For example, you should first work with debug.print.

`InStr` returns a Variant (Long) specifying the position of the first occurrence of one string within another.

**Syntax:** *InStr([ start ], string1, string2, [ compare ])*

The example below uses the InStr function to return the position of the first occurrence of one string within another.

```vb
Dim SearchString, SearchChar, MyPos
SearchString ="XXpXXpXXPXXP"    ' String to search in.
SearchChar = "P"    ' Search for "P".

' A textual comparison starting at position 4. Returns 6.
MyPos = Instr(4, SearchString, SearchChar, 1)    

' A binary comparison starting at position 1. Returns 9.
MyPos = Instr(1, SearchString, SearchChar, 0)

' Comparison is binary by default (last argument is omitted).
MyPos = Instr(SearchString, SearchChar)    ' Returns 9.

MyPos = Instr(1, SearchString, "W")    ' Returns 0.
```

Copied from: [InStr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function)

For a first start you may want to have a look at:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("b2:b6")
        If InStr(cell.Value, "Dr.") > 0 Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Doctor"
        End If
    Next cell
    
End Sub
```

[image]